# C SLRE regex library doesn't work

Tags: c, regex

I'm writing program in C that uses `SLRE` regex to capture strings from HTML page, but it doesn't work.

According to the `SLRE` [documentation](https://github.com/cesanta/slre/blob/master/README.md), `slre_match` returns int thats greater or equal to 0 if there is a match.
In my case there is a match according to the return value but the captures (`slre_cap`) are not make any sense.

That's the function:

```
void GetServers(char* _HTML)
{
    struct slre_cap Matches[1];
    int Ret = 0;
    int HTMLLength = strlen(_HTML);

    Ret = slre_match("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", _HTML, HTMLLength, Matches, 1);

    printf("[Ret: %d]\n", Ret);
    printf("[HTMLLength: %u]\n", HTMLLength);
    printf("[First Match Length: %u]\n", Matches[0].len);
    printf("[First Match Pointer: %u]\n", (int)Matches[0].ptr);
}
```

This is the result:

> [Ret: 1842]
>
> [HTMLLength: 170724]
>
> [First Match Length: 3077990064]
>
> [First Match Pointer: 3220110200]

As you can see `Ret` is greater than 0 which means that we have a match, but the length of the first match (`Matches[0].len`) is greater than the length of the HTML page. How it is possible?

This is the HTML page: http://www.gametracker.com/search/sof2/?searchipp=50&searchpge=1

Comment: Did you try their unit test?

Comment: Yes, unit test passed.

Comment: I don't see [0-9] being supported; only [a-z]; point it out if I missed something.

Comment: Try with `\d`( digit ) instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `[0-9]` is supported because the return value from `slre_match` is correct. Anyway the results are similar with `[a-z]` pattern. edit: `\d` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library doesn't support `[0-9]` syntax. You will have to use `\d`

Like this:

```
Ret = slre_match("(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d)", _HTML, HTMLLength, Matches, 1);
```

Apparently using `"([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"` works too.

Omitting the brackets (), doesn't return an error, yet produces incorrect results, it might be worth reporting the problem.

Comment: Wrapping the whole pattern with brackets solved the problem. Thanks.